# Combining R vectors based on their name

Tags: r

I have plenty of R vectors named like this:
`gna.0` and `gna.1`, also `gni.0` and `gni.1`, and so on

I want to create new vectors like that:

```r
gna <- c(gna.0, gna.1)
gni <- c(gni.0, gni.1)
```

and so on

Can you help?!

Thanks!

Comment: What do yo mean by "named like this"? Which is the pattern? Is it always`gn` + another letter + `.0` or `.1` or can also change `gn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution which would work for any number of similar named objects.

```
#Get all unique group names like gna, gni etc
groups <- unique(sub('\\..*', '', ls(pattern = 'gn')))

#Create a named vector with all the group vectors together
result <- sapply(groups, function(x) 
   unlist(mget(ls(pattern = paste0('\\b', x, '\\b'),.GlobalEnv), 
          .GlobalEnv), use.names = FALSE), simplify = FALSE)

#Write the new vector to global environment
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
#New object gna, gni are created in global environment
```

Comment: It's a nice way to do it but that makes a list with plenty of gn inside. Instead of a list, what can I do to create new vector?

Comment: Do you want to remove the names from each vector? See updated answer if that helps.

Comment: It is better but I have an issue. Because for instance, in gna1 returned vector, I have the data from gna1 but also from gna10, gna11 etc...

Comment: We can add word boundaries around the pattern. See updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ls` to find the variables and `mget` to get their value.

```
gna.0 <- 1:3
gna.1 <- 4:6
gni.0 <- 7:9
gni.1 <- 10:11

gna <- unlist(mget(ls(pattern = "gna.*")), use.names = FALSE)
gna
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

gni <- unlist(mget(ls(pattern = "gni.*")), use.names = FALSE)
gni
#> [1]  7  8  9  10 11
```

Comment: Thank you!
I have many many files and would like to make a loop, with all files starting with "gn".
Can you help?

Comment: You're welcome. If you post another question, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> gna.0 = c(1,2)
> gna.1 = c(3,4)
> gni.0 = c(5,5)
> gni.1 = c(6,6)
> 
> 
> gna = do.call('c', mget(grep("gna",names(.GlobalEnv),value=TRUE)))
> gni = do.call('c', mget(grep("gni",names(.GlobalEnv),value=TRUE)))
> gna
gna.01 gna.02 gna.11 gna.12 
     1      2      3      4 
> gni
gni.01 gni.02 gni.11 gni.12 
     5      5      6      6
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not what I want. I have plenty of files with names starting by "gn", and for each I have it with suffix .0 and .1.
I want to make gna <- c(gna.0, gna.1), using a loop where gna is the name of all my files matching the patter "gn*".